# Should I disable CORS in spring backend? Unathorized request is blocked

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, cors, jwt, axios

I'm working on project with spring boot and Vue, I need to protect my endpoints. The user will have specific role, admin role or typical user role. When I search for tutorials how to configure JWT and spring security I'm getting articles with disabled cors by `cors().disable()` only . And that's my question.. May I send request from my front Vue app via axios if cors in spring backend is disabled? Is it right approach to disable it? A lot of my requests from api were blocked by cors so I enabled it but I didn't implement user roles and it made me confused what to do now because I have to do it... Another problem is when I implemented `httpSecurity.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate", "/register","/login").permitAll().` and tried to call /authenticate from another device in same network then spring blocked it but it shouldn't be blocked.. On the top of controller I have `@CrossOrigin(origins="*", maxAge=3600)` and `@RestController` so I don't know why my request is blocked.
Help me please if You have some ideas.
Best regards!

Comment: Config:
`httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate", "/register","/login").permitAll().
                antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll().
                anyRequest().authenticated().and().
               exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        httpSecurity.cors();`

Comment: CORS allows your backend api to 'talk' to request from different origin. You'll need CORS if you are making an api service, and want allow request originating from different place, Vue app, mobile app, etc. If you disable CORS, your api would only allow request that is originated from the same host as your api service.

Answer (score 0):

Set this in top of every controller

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*") 
@RestController
```

And set the code in SecuriyConfig as follows. It worked for me.

```
httpSecurity.cors()
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/",
                    "/favicon.ico",
                    "/**/*.png",
                    "/**/*.ttf",
                    "/**/*.woff",
                    "/**/*.woff2",
                    "/**/*.gif",
                    "/**/*.svg",
                    "/**/*.jpg",
                    "/**/*.jpeg",
                    "/**/*.html",
                    "/**/*.css",
                    "/**/*.js")
            .permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/authenticate", "/register","/login")
            .permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated();
```